# Why doesn't my select field event handler work in Chrome/Android?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select

the problem is this.

I have a select options, which works well on PC but not on Chrome browser on Android.

What can be wrong?

My HTML:

```
<select id='Button' class='' name='' onchange='' data-native-menu="true">
  <option value="hello">Hello</option>
  <option value="stack">Stack</option>
  <option value="overflow">Overflow</option>
</select>
```

My jQuery:

```
$("#Button").on("click","option",function() {
    var va = $(this).val();
    alert(va);
});
```

My jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/h4g3cfrn/4/

Note: I do not need this in this case `$("#Element").change(function() { // *** Anywhere`.

Comment: Are your WebView configured to deal with DOM and Javascript?

Comment: I have other javascript and jQuery functions running normally.

Comment: Excuse me, maybe I am missing something: I've tried your jsfiddle on both Chromium and Opera (desktop versions) and both didn't work (enabled popups etc). Another point: have you tried using plain Javascript for this?

Comment: Just try it on Firefox desktop and it works fine, how would it be in just javascipt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In plain and pure JavaScript you only need to define a function to deal with the `onChange` event attribute of your `<select>` tag.

**1)** edit your **select** tag to insert this: `myFunction();` as your **onchange** event. Your final tag will look this way:

```
<select id='Button' class='' name='' onchange='myFunction();' data-native-menu="true">
```

**2)** define the following function to deal with the select changes:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var myVar = document.getElementById("Button").value;
  alert(myVar);
}
</script>
```

If you want to try this before: https://jsfiddle.net/u3v5sj12/2/

Best.